# Calling a shader color efficiently

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working with shaders in Three.js for the first time and I can't tweak some of the code that is essential to it, other than just change the RGBA. For example I can't place it inside a `.html()` method. What I'm going for is applying 10 different shader colors.

```
varying vec3 vNormal;
void main() {
  float intensity = pow( 0.4 - dot( vNormal, vec3( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ) ), 4.0 );
  gl_FragColor = vec4( 0, 0, 255, 1.0 ) * intensity; }
  //gl_FragColor = vec4( 0, 0, 255, 1.0 ) is the RGBA value
}
```

As of right now, I can't do anything with that line that I found but just to let it untouched so it'll work. I can only copy the ID on its script tag, tweak the RGBA code and refer it to different `<script>` elements. But I don't want to do that ten times. My code needs to be efficient.

The entire code necessary is inside this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLaxa345/). 
How can and would you change that code so you can easily call a shader color?

Comment: 255 of will fail to compile, '255.' will but it will clamp to 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a uniform for the colour.
[HERE](http://blog.2pha.com/demos/threejs/shaders/single_color.html) you can see the first one I did when starting with Three.js shaders.
but basically it's something like...

HTML/shaders:

```
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
void main() {
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
}
</script>

<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
uniform vec3 diffuse;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(diffuse.x, diffuse.y, diffuse.z, 1.0);
}
</script>
```

Create the shader in JS...

```
var uniforms = {
  diffuse: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color(0xeeeeee) }
};
var vertexShader = document.getElementById('vertexShader').text;
var fragmentShader = document.getElementById('fragmentShader').text;
material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms : uniforms,
  vertexShader : vertexShader,
  fragmentShader : fragmentShader,
});
```

To change the color, change uniforms.diffuse.value.

My example does not include your vNormal and intensity, but you get the idea.
Also, I have my shaders in HTML, but they obviously could just be javascript variables/Strings.

Check [this version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLaxa345/2/)

You may find [THIS](http://blog.2pha.com/experimenting-threejs-shaders-and-shadermaterial) page of other experiments of mine interesting.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your detailed approach to answering my question. Some of your shader materials look very impressing. The fresnel cubemap for instance!

Comment: Do you notice the offset in the fiddle on the meshes? The "glow" is leaning more towards a side rather than emit it equally from the center outwards. How come? Can that be tweaked in the above code?

Comment: I am by no means the one to ask about vector maths as my math skills are extremely poor, but I suspect it has to do with the vectors you are sending to the dot function `dot( vNormal, vec3( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ) )`. You may want the vector from the surface to the camera as the second parameter.